# SFML SoundBuffer to Music buffer

Tags: c++, sfml, soundbuffer

I have SoundBuffer. I want this buffer move to Music.
For now I save in file and read out, but I don't want saving. What can I do?
Now I have this code:

```
sf::SoundBuffer sb = getSoundBuffer(new_channels,sample_rate);
sb.saveToFile("sound.wav");
std::unique_ptr<sf::Music> Buffer(new sf::Music());
Buffer->openFromFile("sound.wav")
 musicAlias[alias] = std::move(Buffer);
...
music->selected = musicAlias[alias].get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `sf::Music` is designed to be used for playing long audio data loaded from a file. If you want to play music that is in a sound buffer, then use `sf::Sound` like this:

```
sf::SoundBuffer sb = getSoundBuffer(new_channels,sample_rate);
std::unique_ptr<sf::Sound> Buffer(new sf::Sound( sb ));
musicAlias[alias] = std::move(Buffer);
...
music->selected = musicAlias[alias].get();
```

You may need to change the type of `musicAlias` to be a container of `std::unique_ptr<sf::Sound>`, but that should work, because the `sf::Sound` class provides a very similar interface as the `sf::Music` class.

Comment: I have error like this: `error: cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr<sf::Sound>::pointer {aka sf::Sound*}' to 'sf::Music*' in assignment
     this->selected = musicAlias[alias].get();`

Comment: @neiiic Well, then change the type of the data member `selected` from `sf::Music*` to `sf::Sound*`. You may need to change types in some other places too. I don't know the rest of your program.

Comment: Now I hear nothing. Without errors. If I replace back to Music, work.

Comment: `sf::SoundBuffer sb = getSoundBuffer(new_channels,sample_rate);
    sb.saveToFile("sound.wav");
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Sound> Buffer(new sf::Sound(sb));
    sf::Sound a;
    a.setBuffer(sb);
    a.play();
    musicAlias[alias] = std::move(Buffer);`

In wav file I can hear ok. But when I play sound in 2 different ways I can not hear anything. Why?

Comment: @neiiic Yeah. A local variable will be destroyed as soon as the function is left. For purposes of code maintainability, please don't make the variable `SoundBuffer` global, but make it a member variable of your class.